# Dynamic tab contents not loading by using ui:include

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, tabview, uiinclude

```
<ui:composition>
    <ui:decorate template="/view-fragments/section/frag_section.xhtml" >
        <ui:param name="AttrId" value="SOME_VALUE" />
        <ui:param name="AttrMinimized" value="false" />
        <ui:define name="AttrContentTitle">
            Some Title
        </ui:define>
        <ui:param name="AttrCollapsable" value="false" />
        <ui:define name="AttrContentBody">

            <h:form id="form_some_form" class="form-horizontal">

                <p:tabView id="tabView" widgetVar="tabView" dynamic="true" rendered="true" cache="true">
                    <p:tab id="tab1" title="title1">

                    </p:tab>

                    <ui:include src="/view-fragments/project/frag_tab2.xhtml" />
                    <ui:include src="/view-fragments/project/frag_tab3.xhtml" />
                    <ui:include src="/view-fragments/project/frag_tab4.xhtml" />
                    <ui:include src="/view-fragments/project/frag_tab5.xhtml" />
                    <ui:include src="/view-fragments/project/frag_tab6.xhtml" />


                </p:tabView>

            </h:form>


        </ui:define>
    </ui:decorate>
</ui:composition>
```

This doesn't load tab2, tab3...etc. content to the tabView. but the content is shown if I take it off the p:tabView. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: This thread may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111010/jsf-dynamically-include-src-in-uiinclude-src-bean-pagepath