# tabClose method is not called for the first tab from tabview primefaces

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces, tabs

I use primefaces version 5.3 and jsf version 2.2.6.

I implemented a tabClose ajax event for a tabview, but the problem is that for the first tab, the tabClose event isn't triggered and the method remove isn't called, for all the other tabs, it is and it works and I can't understand why.
Additionally, if I try to close the first tab, all the tabs are closed.

The code looks like this:

```
<p:tabView id="tabs" activeIndex="#{mainPage.index}">
        <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{mainPage.remove}" update="formTabs" />
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{mainPage.changeTab}" update="formTabs" />

        <c:forEach items="#{mainPage.tabs}" var="tab" varStatus="loop">
            <p:tab title="#{tab.title}" closable="true">
                <f:subview id="tab#{loop.index}">
                <ui:debug />
                    <ui:include src="#{tab.url}">
                        <ui:param name="focusedTab" value="#{tab.id}" />
                    </ui:include>
                </f:subview>
            </p:tab>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:tabView>
```

Does anybody know what the cause could be?

Comment: I implemented that at first, but the problem was as described in the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111010/jsf-dynamically-include-src-in-uiinclude-src-bean-pagepath) and then I used what you said in there.

Comment: Primefaces version 5.3

Comment: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=44985&p=140737#p140737

Comment: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=44985&p=140762#p140762

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above explained problem was solved by adding dynamic="true" in the tabView. But after that it appeared another obstacle, when the switch between tabs was made, all the tabs disappeared. That was solved by adding cache="false"